# Data sorting out to new files

Tags: shell, awk

I have a logfile looks like this:

```
 [2013-08-16 03:24:39,192][INFO ][AbstractServiceInvoker          [SID:187175558][] Received request of type [ReportNotification]
```

I need two write out every line to a new file if contains [INFO ] to a file called the SID name, like 187175558_xyz.txt

Thanks for helping!

Comment: `I need two write out every line to...` we need to see your codes and know where were you stuck.

Comment: I'm just do a grep for [INFO ], but i need it in a script and no idea what can i do to print it to a file called the lines SID name.

Answer (score 0):

This prints the output to filname defined by the SID name

```
awk -F":|]" '/INFO/ {print $0 >> $6 "_xyz.txt"}' file
```

Comment: It gives me a syntax error: awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 /INFO/ {print $0 >> $6 >>>  "_xyz.txt" <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1

Comment: Can't locate where's the problem. Trying to modify, but no luck.

Comment: Works fine in my Ubuntu, it may be awk version you are using. What do you use?

Comment: Ok. I will try it. How can i make this line into a script file?

Comment: This script writes the INFO lines to file. I need to make every INFO line to a new file that called the SID number_xyz.txt

Comment: You probably want to use `>` instead of `>>` for the output redirection so it inits the output file when invoked. Also, you don't need the explicit `$0`. That FS looks odd too - I assume you mean fields are separated by `:` or `]` characters but I'm not sure most awks would know what to do with a `]` in that location. Just write it as a character list `-F'[]:]'`. Finally - the most likely cause of the syntax error is that the string concatenation following output redirection MUST be parenthesized as `print > ($6 "_xyz.txt")` or it can be interpreted as `(print > $6) "_xyz.txt"` by some awks.

Comment: To summarize, change the script to: `awk -F'[]:]' '/INFO/ {print > ($6 "_xyz.txt")}' file`